# Kafka consumer sleep wakeup

Tags: java, spring-kafka, consumer, pause

Hello I have a batch using Spring boot with a kafka consumer annotated with `@KafkaListener` during treatment a have a static boolean that takes differents values during running I want to paused my consommer if true and wake it up when false I dont want to lose messages when the consumer is paused
Info a have multiple partition for the topic
How can I do that thank you

Paused my kafka listener if condition and not lose messages during this pause

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The pause functionality on the container is just a request to move to that state when consume loop is ready. While you are in processing of your just pulled batch, that thread is blocked and cannot react to your pause request immediately. So, you really don't lose records you are processing now. The new batch is not going to be pulled because that consumer loop will see a pause request.

See more info in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#pause-resume